# std::condition_variable::wait Access Violation

Tags: multithreading, c++11, concurrency

I'm currently programming a concurrent queue while learning how to use the multithreading features of C++11.
When the consumer calls the `dequeue()` function and the queue has no entries, the function should wait until another thread calls `enqueue()`. I'm using a `condition_variable` for that.
My tests worked fine with a few entries and threads, but when I'm using more (up to 100000 elements, 20 producers, only 1 consumer), I get an Access Violation inside the `condition_variable::wait` function:

> Unbehandelte Ausnahme bei 0x5A2C7EEC (msvcr110d.dll) in Tests.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Zugriffsverletzung beim Lesen an Position 0xFEEEFEF6

I've been stuck with this for hours. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

The Code:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Concurrent Queue
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma once
#include <atomic> // Atomic operations for lock-free operations
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;


// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Declarations
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<typename T>
class ConcurrentQueue;

template<typename T>
class ConcurrentQueueEntry;


// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Queue
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<typename T>
class ConcurrentQueue {
public:
    ConcurrentQueue();
    ~ConcurrentQueue();

    void enqueue(const T value);
    T try_dequeue();
    T dequeue();

    unsigned long count() const;

private:
    atomic<ConcurrentQueueEntry<T>*> front;
    atomic<ConcurrentQueueEntry<T>*> rear;

    atomic_ulong i_count;

    mutex dequeueWaitMutex;
    condition_variable dequeueWaitCV;
};


// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Entry
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<typename T>
class ConcurrentQueueEntry {
public:
    ConcurrentQueueEntry(T _value);

    T value;
    atomic<ConcurrentQueueEntry<T>*> next;
};


// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Exception: Queue is empty
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class EmptyQueueException {};


// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Constructors and Destructor
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Create Queue
template<typename T>
ConcurrentQueue<T>::ConcurrentQueue()
    : front(), rear(), i_count(), dequeueWaitMutex(), dequeueWaitCV()
{
    i_count.store(0);
}

// Delete Queue
template<typename T>
ConcurrentQueue<T>::~ConcurrentQueue()
{
    ConcurrentQueueEntry<T>* previous = this->front.load();
    while(previous != NULL) {
        ConcurrentQueueEntry<T>* next = previous->next.load();
        delete previous;
        previous = next;
    }
}

// Create Entry
template<typename T>
ConcurrentQueueEntry<T>::ConcurrentQueueEntry
    (T _value)
    : value(_value), next(NULL)
{ }


// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Public Methods
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Enqueue
template<typename T>
void ConcurrentQueue<T>::enqueue
    (const T value)
{
    // create, append
    ConcurrentQueueEntry<T>* entry = new ConcurrentQueueEntry<T>(value);
    ConcurrentQueueEntry<T>* former_rear = this->rear.exchange(entry);

    // connect
    if(former_rear == NULL) {
        this->front.store(entry);
    }
    else {
        former_rear->next.store(entry);
    }

    // Add
    ++i_count;
    dequeueWaitCV.notify_one();
}

// Dequeue (aborts if queue is empty)
template<typename T>
T ConcurrentQueue<T>::try_dequeue()
{
    ConcurrentQueueEntry<T>* front = this->front.load();
    while(front != NULL && 
        !this->front.compare_exchange_weak(front, front->next.load())); 

    if(front == NULL)
        throw EmptyQueueException();

    --i_count;
    T value = front->value;
    delete front;
    return value;
}

// Dequeue (waits if queue is empty)
template<typename T>
T ConcurrentQueue<T>::dequeue() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            return this->try_dequeue();
        }
        catch(EmptyQueueException) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(dequeueWaitMutex);
            dequeueWaitCV.wait(lock, [&] { return this->count() == 0; });
        }
    }
}

// Count entries
template<typename T>
unsigned long ConcurrentQueue<T>::count() const {
    return this->i_count.load();
}
```

The Call Stack:

```
msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::LockQueueNode::IsTicketValid() Zeile 924    C++
msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::LockQueueNode::UpdateQueuePosition(Concurrency::details::LockQueueNode * pPreviousNode) Zeile 811   C++
msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::critical_section::_Acquire_lock(void * _PLockingNode, bool _FHasExternalNode) Zeile 1193 C++
msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::critical_section::lock() Zeile 1028  C++
msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::_Condition_variable::wait(Concurrency::critical_section & _Lck) Zeile 576   C++
msvcp110d.dll!do_wait(_Cnd_internal_imp_t * * cond, _Mtx_internal_imp_t * * mtx, const xtime * target) Zeile 47 C++
msvcp110d.dll!_Cnd_wait(_Cnd_internal_imp_t * * cond, _Mtx_internal_imp_t * * mtx) Zeile 73 C++
Tests.exe!std::_Cnd_waitX(_Cnd_internal_imp_t * * _Cnd, _Mtx_internal_imp_t * * _Mtx) Zeile 93  C++
Tests.exe!std::condition_variable::wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> & _Lck) Zeile 60   C++
Tests.exe!std::condition_variable::wait<<lambda_61c2d1dffb87d02ed418fe62879bb063> >(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> & _Lck, ConcurrentQueue<long>::dequeue::__l7::<lambda_61c2d1dffb87d02ed418fe62879bb063> _Pred) Zeile 67    C++
Tests.exe!ConcurrentQueue<long>::dequeue() Zeile 156    C++
Tests.exe!<lambda_c8c79a4136723f6fef9d0a0557ed768b>::operator()() Zeile 38  C++
Tests.exe!std::_Bind<0,void,<lambda_c8c79a4136723f6fef9d0a0557ed768b>,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>::operator()() Zeile 1152   C++
Tests.exe!std::_LaunchPad<std::_Bind<0,void,<lambda_c8c79a4136723f6fef9d0a0557ed768b>,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil> >::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<std::_Bind<0,void,<lambda_c8c79a4136723f6fef9d0a0557ed768b>,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil> > * _Ln) Zeile 196  C++
Tests.exe!std::_LaunchPad<std::_Bind<0,void,<lambda_c8c79a4136723f6fef9d0a0557ed768b>,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil> >::_Go() Zeile 187 C++
msvcp110d.dll!_Call_func(void * _Data) Zeile 52 C++
msvcr110d.dll!_callthreadstartex() Zeile 354    C
msvcr110d.dll!_threadstartex(void * ptd) Zeile 337  C
kernel32.dll!747f850d() Unbekannt
[Unten angegebene Rahmen sind möglicherweise nicht korrekt und/oder fehlen, keine Symbole geladen für kernel32.dll] 
ntdll.dll!7719bf39()    Unbekannt
ntdll.dll!7719bf0c()    Unbekannt
```

Comment: Im getting the same thing, seeing a lot of crashes when LockQueueNode::UpdateQueuePosition is called. Im starting to think there might be a race condition in the visual studio runtime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two notes up front for debugging:

- 0xFEEEFEF6 is 0xFEEEFEEE + 8. The 0xFEEEFEEE is a signal value which the debug runtime stores in some variables. I think that this value indicates that the owning object's destructor was already called. In contrast, before initialization, the value is 0xCDCDCDCD I think.
- You can configure VS to turn off internationalization. That way you get English error messages, which are more suitable for the forum here.

Now, concerning your code, the first thing is that this is not "the code" but rather just part thereof. Distil a minimal example, please. However, in the meantime, you could make your queue class uncopyable and unassignable (using ".. = delete;"). If I'm guessing right, you will then get compile errors which come from copying the queue, probably during thread startup.