# ManualResetEvent with std::condition_variable access violation

Tags: c++

I wrote a ManualResetEvent with std and it's working great 99.9999% of the time. In that other 0.0001% of cases there's either a write or a read access violation on the 'WaitOne' routine. Here's the code:

```
    class ManualResetEvent {
    private:
        std::condition_variable condition;
        std::mutex mut;
        std::atomic<bool> state;

    public:
        ManualResetEvent(bool initialState) {
            state.store(initialState);
        }

        bool Set() {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
            state.store(true);
            condition.notify_all();

            return true;
        }

        bool Reset() {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
            state.store(false);
            return true;
        }

        bool WaitOne() {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
            condition.wait(lock, [&]() {return state.load(); });

            return true;
        }
    }
```

If the error is a read access violation VS tells me 'Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::_Mutex_base::_Mymtx(...) returned 0x...' and shows the code where it fails in std::condition_variable:

```
void wait(unique_lock<mutex>& _Lck) { // wait for signal
    // Nothing to do to comply with LWG-2135 because std::mutex lock/unlock are nothrow
    _Cnd_wait(_Mycnd(), _Lck.mutex()->_Mymtx());
}
```

If I replace all the std with windows specific apis (CreateEvent) it works great as well, 100% of the time. So what am I doing wrong with std::condition_variable?

Comment: Everything is fine. Your bug is somewhere else.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17245418/580083.

Comment: Maybe you are you trying to destruct the ManualResetEvent while holding the lock?
I think you need some synchronization in the destructor of ManualResetEvent (e.g. add a lock there too)

Comment: No, my other code is fine, if I replace the std::condition_variable with a 'sleep loop' it works fine, same if I replace it with CreateEvent and friends.

Comment: @LeonRiemann _"if I replace the std::condition_variable with a 'sleep loop' it works fine, same if I replace it with CreateEvent and friends"_ — This really doesn't imply that your other code is fine. It very likely is not.

Comment: A basic way to repro this crash is auto m = new ManualResetEvent(false); delete m; m->wait();  That's an obvious way to do it, in practice it is more convoluted with the object being a member of a class that doesn't implement the rule-of-zero.

Comment: If you use this ManualResetEvent in multiple threads have you ensured that the lifetime of the ManualResetEvent is longer then any of the threads accessing it? E.g. do you synchronize with all threads before destroying it, or do you extend the lifetime of the ManualResetEvent by sharing ownership (shared_ptr) of the ManualResetEvent between the threads?

Comment: Adding a destructor with a lock didn't help it. However, I noticed if I put a debug message (read a small delay) right after the condition.wait it seems to solve or at least improve the problem. It seems like either the lock or the mutex are getting destroyed while the wait thread hasn't finished.

Comment: @Pepijn, to answer your question, I'm using reference counting which destroys/recycles the ManualResetEvent after either the wait or the set, whichever happens last. I'm reasonably sure this is working as intended and that the memory is there whenever I'm in any of those methods.

Comment: okay, then I am out of ideas for the moment.

Comment: In fact when I don't destroy the ManualResetEvent at all, by using the reset method and reusing it, I have the exact same issue.